# jasmine, javascript

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

i just started with learning Javascript and Jasmine and stumbled about the following error Message when i run the test: "ReferenceError: greet is not defined"

```
// greetSpec.js

  describe('greeter', function() {
    return it('should greet with message and name', function() {
      var result;
      result = greet('Hello', 'John Doe');
      return expect(result).toBe('Hello, John Doe!');
    });
  });


// greet.js    

      var greet;

      greet = function(message, person) {
        var greeting;
        return greeting = "" + message + ", " + person + "!";
      };
```

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question as it stands, you should state what your problem is and what you've tried. Anyway you're going to have to make sure greet is visible to your jasmine file.

Comment: What's the point of setting a local variable `greeting` inside the return statement and returning it?

Comment: @AndrewBarrett , how can i make sure, that greet is visible to my jasmine file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>The function is defined *before* the declaration of `greet`. Think of the file being scanned from top-to-bottom. By the time it gets to the `describe` call, the variable `greet` does not exist, hence the error. Try putting the greet function definition above the call.</strike>

Turns out, as Lennier put it, that there was "a conflict between some of the coffeescript generated files." Glad I could help though.

Comment: there are two different files: greet.js and greetSpec.js

Comment: Make sure greet.js is defined above greetSpec.js

Comment: Can you post the definition of `describe`? I can't think of any other reason why this is not working. Are you sure this is the full code for each file?

Comment: there was a conflict between some of the coffeescript generated files.